# How to specify latex compiler?

Tags: luatex, compiling

Hello I am the very noob for Latex.

I know there are many latex compiler implementations. (pdflatex, lualatex and so on..)
My concern is, how can I specify and notify the compiler I used to who will recieve my tex file? When I send my tex file to a conference or a journal, how do they know that they should use luatex for compiling?

For example, if I use "\luacode" directive, it would be failed to becompiled on pdflatex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which front-end editor to you employ? Or do you compile your latex documents from the command line?

Comment: Hi, John! First, you have to know if the target journal accepts LuaTeX (many don't). Second, the LaTeX compiler is specified according to your text editor: e.g. in TeXstudio you use `%!TEX program = ` magical comments.

Comment: Basically you will have to tell them. E.g. as a comment as the begin of the file, or in the mail when sending the article.